# Wordpress uses a different theme for anonymous users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Strange issue is happening in a website I am trying to setup in Wordpress. When I am logged in to the site as Admin I get the correct theme to apply. However, if I am logged out(Anonymous) the theme applied is TwelveFifteen. I cannot see any settings that is forcing that and I have not added any code to do it either. Has anyone seen this issue or can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Your theme is purchase theme or default wordpress theme?

Comment: Hi @Samyappa ... it is a purchased theme

Comment: i think mostly settings their from your theme, better refer your theme documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the Porcelain theme and its Child Theme http://pexetothemes.com/docs/porcelain/#child_theme 

I didn't see anything there as of yet. But I will keep looking. Thanks